# How to use dependency in Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dependency-injection, referenceerror

I'm mostly a backend dev but I now need to implement something in an existing vue codebase. In a file called `myModal.vue` I need to use a [this cron-parser js lib](https://github.com/harrisiirak/cron-parser). When I use it in the `app.js` file it works perfectly:

```
import CronParser from 'cron-parser';

let interval = CronParser.parseExpression('*/2 * * * *');
console.log(interval.next().toString()); // logs a correct datetime
```

So I now want to pass this CronParser to the `myModal.vue` file. So following an existing injection of HighCharts I added the third of these 4 lines:

```
Vue.prototype.$eventHub = new Vue();
Vue.use(HighchartsVue);
Vue.use(CronParser);

let myModal = require('./components/myModal.vue');
// and some more components
```

Then in `myModal.vue` I use the same code:

```
let interval = CronParser.parseExpression('*/2 * * * *');
console.log(interval.next().toString());
```

But I now get

```
"ReferenceError: CronParser is not defined"
```

I'm kinda lost on where I'm going wrong here though. Could anybody hint me in the right direction

Comment: `Vue.use` is to register Vue plugin module, not to pass around stuff to Vue. You can import in `.vue` files like you did in the `.js` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CronParser` is not a vue library, you wouldn't use it as such `Vue.use(CronParser);`

Instead, just make sure you import it in your `myModal.vue`. It looks like you may be missing `import CronParser from 'cron-parser';` in there.